# Group by and filter based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, group-by

I want to drop a whole group if a condition on one column is satisfied,  (don't pay attention to Column X1 and X2)  :

```
 Subject  Visit           X1      X2
   A       aaa          1647143  1672244
   A       creamy       1672244  1689707
   A       bbb          1689707  1713090
   B       yyy          1735352  1760283
   B       ice cream    1760283  1788062
   C       foo          1788062  1789885
   C       doo          1789885  1790728
```

exemple if "Visit" contains the string "cream"  all Subject A and Subject B records will be deleted and result would be :

```
Subject  Visit      X1      X2

 C       foo    1788062  1789885
 C       doo    1789885  1790728
```

I tried : and it didn't delete the whole group records

```
df.groupby(by=['Subject']).apply(lambda d: d[~d['Visit'].str.contains('cream',flags=re.I, regex=True)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```py
df.groupby("Subject").filter(lambda gr: ~gr.Visit.str.contains("cream").any())
```

to get

```
  Subject Visit       X1       X2
5       C   foo  1788062  1789885
6       C   doo  1789885  1790728
```

We filter on "keep the groups that do not (`~`) contain (`str.contains`) any (`any`) `"cream"` in the `Visit` column".

Answer (score 0):

Groupby then check if `Visit` column if each group contains `cream` string.

```py
def move_group(group):
    if not any(group['Visit'].str.contains('cream')):
        return group

df_ = df.groupby('Subject').apply(move_group).dropna()
```

```
# print(df_)

  Subject Visit         X1         X2
5       C   foo  1788062.0  1789885.0
6       C   doo  1789885.0  1790728.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use transform to assign `True/False` to the elements of `group` depending on the condition if group contains 'cream' or 'not'. Then drop the rows with `False` value.

```
mask = (df1.groupby('Subject')['Visit']
        .transform(lambda d: np.any(
              d.str.contains('cream', flags = re.I, regex = True)))
        )
df = df[~mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by first creating the column which checks for the presence of `cream`, then filter using `transform`, but on the sum of the booleans:

```
(df
.assign(cream = df.Visit.str.contains("cream"))
.loc[lambda df: df.groupby("Subject")
                  .cream
                  .transform("sum")==0, 
     df.columns]
)
Out[14]: 
  Subject Visit       X1       X2
5       C   foo  1788062  1789885
6       C   doo  1789885  1790728
```